# how to target component styles from host component angular 2

Tags: angular

I have this :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'host-element',
    template: `<elementA></elementA>`,
    styles:[''] //styles here
})

export class hostElement {}
```

How do I target the styles of `elementA` component from `host-element`?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
:host elementA {
  // style here
}
```

Comment: For me, this creates the result of "[__ngcontent-c3] elementA[__ngcontent-c3] { /*style here */ }", which just has the same result as if I had just put "elementA{ /*style here*/ }".  How can I create the result of "[__ngcontent-c3] elementA { /*style here*/ }"?

Comment: looks like the other answer is what you are looking for

Comment: I had read elsewhere that the /deep/ operator was being depreciated, but I don't actually see anything about that in the angular docs, so looks like that should do it for me, thanks.

Comment: It's deprecated in Chrome, other browsers never supported it. Angular emulates it and doesn't depend on browser support, but it only works in `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` (default)

Answer (score 4):

Angular has a special css operator `/deep/`, you can read about [it here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html).

To make a style go beyond your component, put in your css (sass, less):

```
/deep/ .elemet-a-class {
   ... your style;
}
```

Or if you want to put it locally, just

```
styles: ['/deep/ .element-a-class { ... }']
```

Comment: For newer versions use :host {}, as deep has been deprecated https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep